# ECMAScript2015 compatibility

Tags: lightning-aura-components, es6, lightning-cli

As I understand it, the platform uses closure compiler to transpile code. And closure compiler officially supports ECMAScript 6 since 2015. But lightning-cli is configured to not allow version 6 or higher inside lightning components. Although, it is allowed to use it outside of component.

**The question is:**

Will we be allowed to use some ES2015 features at some point in the future?

Comment: I do know that support for ECMAScript 6 it's in the Lightning Component Team's product plan, but can't say when it will be delivered. Security and Locker Service compliance is their #1 priority. Without a secure Lightning platform, it won't matter to your org what version of ECMAScript you're using when writing your components.

Answer (score 8):

It is possible to use some features of ECMAScript 6 in lightning components, here are some of the ones that I am aware of:

> - [ES6 Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)
> - BlockScope Variables ([Let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) and [Const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const))
> - [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
> - [Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)
> - [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
> - [Default Parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)
> - [Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Documentation links for the aformentioned ES6 Features (if any):

- [Using JavaScript Promises](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_promises.htm)
- [Introduction To ECMAScript 6](https://www.salesforce.com/video/303941/)

Ideas for ES6 Features on the success community:

- [Arrow functions, let, and const in Lightning Components](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CSQ6QAO) (although already supported)
- [ES6 Lambda support in Lightning component controllers](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000Tu55QAC)
- [Enable Lightning Component Developers to Use TypeScript and EcmaScript 6](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CPrdQAG) (Several if not most of these features are already supported)

Unfortunately, there doesnt seem to be any official documentation on ES6 Supported features

Comment: do you have any Salesforce documentation that says what ECMAScript 6 is safe to use in Lightning Components?

Comment: Other than testing myself - I know there was a presentation at dreamforce 2 years ago on the subject. I can dig a bit to see if i find any documetnation links, but I have tested the above in my lightning components, and those specific features are supported. I think there is a Developer blog for the ES6 promises

Comment: I found the reference for [Using JavaScript Promies](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_promises.htm) in Lightning but haven't found anything describing specific support for ES6.  Does lightning shim the ES6 if not supported on a Client?  I don't want my Component to break on older browsers

Comment: Unfortunately, there doesnt seem to be any official documentation on ES6 Supported features. =( , the above links are the only ones I was able to find.

Comment: Top-level arrow functions won't deploy, though they seem ok _inside_ controller functions. That's a real shame in 2023.

Answer (score 0):

Will we be allowed to use some ES2015 features at some point in the future?
yes definitely.

At the moment this what the documentation says and there is no explicit error thrown when we use ES6 syntax but it might not work in IE11. If you are building products in AppExchange better to stick to ES5

### Supported JavaScript

The Aura Components programming model supports ES5 syntax and ES6 Promises.
For the most reliable experience, use ES5 to develop Aura components because the pipeline from authoring to serialization to execution was built for ES5. Promises from ES6 are also available. Using any other syntax or feature is not supported, and does not work in IE11.

This developer guide explains how to develop Aura components and documents the JavaScript usage that's unique to the Aura Components programming model.

If you want to use ES6 or later for development, use the Lightning Web Components programming model, which has been architected for modern JavaScript development.