# Can I assume ECMAScript 6 maps and sets are available anywhere a Lightning Component can run?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

When writing JavaScript logic in a Lightning Component controller or helper using the [ECMAScript 6: maps and sets](http://2ality.com/2015/01/es6-maps-sets.html) would lead to cleaner code in some cases.

There is mention of Map and Set in this Lightning Components [Collection Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_attr_types_collection.htm) documentation but that may be conceptual (or be related to Apex types). This Salesforce Lightning CLI Rules [Validate JavaScript Intrinsic APIs (ecma-intrinsics)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/cli_rules_ecma_intrinsic.htm?search_text=ecmascript) documentation links to ECMAScript documentation that includes Map and Set.

Map and Set are available in Chrome. But can I assume they available anywhere a Lightning Component can run?

**PS**

This asks a similar but broader question [ECMAScript2015 compatibility](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/164886/ecmascript2015-compatibility) and does not have an accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Maps`, `Sets`, `Weakmaps` and `Weaksets` are all supported by Lockerservice even though they don't have any official documentation explicitly stating so. You can check their [SecureWindow compatibility table](http://documentation.auraframework.org/lockerApiTest/secureWindow.app?aura.mode=DEV) and note that the actual columns for Browser API and Locker API both state `function` instead of `Not To Be Supported`.

Comment: Thanks should have looked there. Can you confirm that the [supported browsers](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=getstart_browsers_sfx.htm&type=0) all support Map and Set?

Comment: Browser support is good enough for [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) except for IE 11 which has partial support.